# Jira jql updated between two dates

Tags: jira, jql

In Jira how do you find tickets worked on (updated) between two different dates ?

I tried this
project = XYZ  and updated >  '2024-01-10' and updated <  '2024-02-10'

This produces fewer results than expected because if a ticket is updated multiple times including after the maximum date it is omitted

Comment: Seems like the "Updated" field only contains the record of the last update, not a history of all updates ever...

Comment: Can you explain why you want to query all issues that were updated between two dates?
At my job, we would start separate Sprints per month or so, so those Sprints would more or less contain the issues that belong to a certain period of time...

Comment: You could also use some external scripting that for example scans the Jira database every day to collect all issues that changed in the last day/week... This will not collect historical data for you, unfortunately...

Comment: for reports, number of tickets worked on between x dates etc. it's used as a support kamban board so dosen't fit sprints as we have to work on them as they come in.